# Fireplace wall switch

Tags: fireplace

I have a Napoleon brand gas log fireplace set. It is turned on/off by means of a remote. A receiver is wired to the gas valve that takes the signal from the remote. The receiver operates on 4 batteries. The igniter is also activated via a 4 battery pack starter. We replace batteries often and want to rid of the remote and wire direct to a switch. My understanding is that the battery packs could be eliminated. There is also a blower in the lower compartment that can be turned on/off to help circulate warm air. I mention this as there is electricity to that compartment. The blower is plugged into an outlet within the lower compartment. The blower is not thermostatically controlled. Is it possible to add a wall switch (there is an unused wall switch in wall I am hoping to utilize). I realize low voltage wire is required. Below the floor is a drop ceiling in basement so access to wall outlet and running wire wouldn’t be a problem. Gas line is run in that same area.